# How to configure self signed ssl with public ip address in XAMPP (windows)?

Tags: ssl, openssl, self-signed

I am trying to configure a self signed ssl certificate to one of my servers. I have 3 servers. I am using 1 public ip for all three servers. To do that i am using port forwarding. I know by using openssl i can configure a self signed ssl for localhost(private network). I have below questions regarding my problem. I am using xampp in windows server.

1. Is it possible to configure self signed ssl certificate for a public ip-address with port? if yes 
   then how can i do that ?

I have seen some tutorial to configure self signed certificates but all of them are for private ip.

Answer (score 0):

Meta: this is really an operations question, not programming or development, and offtopic for SO

An HTTPS server (like Apache) must use a certificate that includes the name *used to access it* i.e. in the URL(s) used by clients, *excluding* any port specification. This can be a domain name or an IP address (any kind: v4 or v6, public or private, as long as using that address from the client(s) reaches the correct server). This means that multiple servers at different ports on the same address *can* use the same cert if you wish, but they also be different if you prefer.

A *public* CA will only issue a cert containing a domainname or address you can prove you own, which is only possible for a *fully-qualified* domainname in public DNS or a 'permanent' public address, but for a cert you create yourself that restriction doesn't apply.

Since the turn of the century you should use the Subject Alternative Name (SAN) extension, not solely the CommonName attribute in Subject as you may find in many websites and blogs that copy outdated or incorrect information. SAN can specify more than one name if desired, but note each item in it explicitly specifies DNS or IPaddress; be sure to use the correct one(s). All popular software has supported SAN for years, but so far only Chrome(ium) *requires* it. OpenSSL *can* create certs with extensions like SAN, but not with its simplest method, which is very popular with outdated or wrong websites, namely `req -new` followed by basic `x509 -req`. See:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/150078/missing-x509-extensions-with-an-openssl-generated-certificate
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371997/creating-a-local-ssl-certificate
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/393601/local-ssl-certificates-in-chrome-ium-63

PS: Windows is irrelevant, except that you probably need to install OpenSSL whereas on many Unices it is already present by default